# Overloading prefix increment operator for iterator class throws segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I'm getting segmentation faults when the iterator reaches the last node in class the linked list.
By debugging, I can see that when the iterator reaches the end of the linked list, `node->next_` points to null and thus throws the seg fault.

EDIT:

I've include the definition for `void push_front()` method

List.h

```cpp
    void push_front(const T& value) {
        
        Node* node = new Node(value, nullptr, nullptr);

        if (head_ == nullptr) {
            head_ = node;
            tail_ = head_;
        }
        else {
            node->next_ = head_;
            head_ = node;
        }
    }
```

I tried to change the overloaded operator to the follow with no luck:

```cpp
iterator& operator++() {
    iNode = iNode->next_;  //this line throws the exception
    return *this;
}

//and

iterator& operator++() {
    return ++(*this);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
#include <string>

int main(){

    List<int> l1;

    l1.push_front(4);
    l1.push_front(3);
    l1.push_front(2);
    l1.push_front(1);
    l1.push_front(0);


    for (auto i = l1.begin(); i != l1.end(); ++i)
    {
        int j = 0;  
    }

    l1.printList();
}
```

List.h

```cpp
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:

    class Node {
    public:

        Node(T value, Node* prev, Node* next) : value_(value), prev_(prev), next_(next) {}

        T value_;
        Node* next_;
        Node* prev_;
    };

    Node* head_;
    Node* tail_;

    //! An iterator over the list
    class iterator
    {
    public:

        Node* iNode;
        iterator(Node* head): iNode(head){ }
        ~iterator() {}

        T& operator*() {
            return  iNode -> value_;
        }
    
        //prefix increment
        iterator& operator++() {
            this->iNode = this->iNode->next_;  //this line throws the exception
            return *this;

        }
           
        //postfix increment
        iterator operator++(int ignored) {
            iterator result = *this; 
            ++(*this); 
            return result;
        }

        bool operator== (const iterator& it) const {
            return iNode == it.iNode;
        }

        bool operator!= (const iterator& it) const {
            return !(iNode == it.iNode);
        }
     };

//! Get an iterator to the beginning of the list
    iterator begin() {
        return List<T>::iterator(head_);
    }

    //! Get an iterator just past the end of the list
    iterator end() {
        return List<T>::iterator(nullptr);
    }
};
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `push_back`? Maybe the linked list itself is corrupted.

Comment: `iterator& operator++() { return ++(*this); }` causes undefined behaviour (infinite recursion)

Comment: @cigien I've included the definition for `push_front()`

Comment: The iterator class does not appear to define `operator!=` so I do not see how `i != l1.end()` is working

Comment: @M.M I actually do have the definition for that. Sorry for not including it.

Comment: @cigien I think you're right. It's something to do with the definition of `push_front()` since using `push_back()` works fine

Comment: I actually meant `push_front`. I didn't know you had a `push_back`, that was a typo.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, after adding an `operator!=` and commenting out the `l1.printList();`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e04329a7284f721 Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You never use the `prev_` member (even when you `push_front` you still leave it `nullptr`).

Comment: @aschepler I will provide it, just a moment.

Comment: @aschepler I put the full code in [this](http://cpp.sh/5qmel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `head_` to `nullptr` by default:

```
Node* head_ = nullptr;
```

otherwise `head_` has some indeterminate value, and the following check in `push_front` is not guaranteed to work:

```
if (head_ == nullptr)
```

even though `head_` is not pointing to valid memory.

Note that this problem arises even if you never call `push_front`, because in the `for` loop check the `begin` iterator's `iNode` may not be `nullptr`, even if the List is empty. This means `i` will be incremented, which causes UB in the `operator++` when accessing `next_`.

Here's a [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SyDCAHgCI). (If you don't initialize `head_`, the program segfaults.)